# How to use TimeSeriesSplit in cv as mentioned in the documentation of scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

Trying to use 10 fold `TimeSeriesSplit()`, but in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) of `cross_val_score`, it is given that we need to pass a cross-validation generator or an iterable.

```py
tss = TimeSeriesSplit(max_train_size=None, n_splits=10)
l =[]
neighb = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,12,23,19,18]
for k in neighb:
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k, algorithm='brute')
    sc = cross_val_score(knn, X1, y1, cv=tss, scoring='accuracy')
    l.append(sc.mean())
```

How should I pass it after the time-series split into train and test data to `cv`?

```py
TypeError                   
 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-acf06bc7340e> in <module>()
     14 for k in neighb:
     15     knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k, algorithm='brute')
---> 16     sc = cross_val_score(knn, X1, y1, cv=tss, scoring='accuracy')
     17     l.append(sc.mean())
     18 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
   1579                                               train, test, verbose, None,
   1580                                               fit_params)
-> 1581                       for train, test in cv)
   1582     return np.array(scores)[:, 0]
   1583 
TypeError: 'TimeSeriesSplit' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Trying to use 10 fold TimeSeries Split, but in the documentation of cross_val_score, it is given that we need to pass a cross-validation generator or an iterable. How should I pass it after time series split into train and test data to cv

Comment: I have updated the answer, see the Edit2. Thats why I was asking for full code.

Comment: It works after removing the deprecated class.

Comment: @VivekKumar would you check this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75818230/10452700)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass `tss` to `cv`.

```
scores = cross_val_score(knn, X_train, y_train, cv=tss , scoring='accuracy')
```

No need to call `tss.split()`.

**Update**:
The above method is tested on scikit-learn v0.19.1 . So make sure you have the latest version. Also I am using [TimeSeriesSplit from model_selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html) module.

**Edit 1**:

You are using this now:

```
tss = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=10).split(X_1)
kn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, algorithm='brute') 
sc = cross_val_score(kn, X1, y1, cv=tss, scoring='accuracy')
```

But in the question you posted you did this:

```
tss = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=10)
```

See the difference between them (`split()` is not present). I am using this `tss` in the `cross_val_score()` without the `split()` as you posted in the question.

**Edit 2**:

Dude you are using the deprecated class. 
Currently you are doing this:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
```

This is wrong. You should get a warning like this:

> DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor
>   of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes
>   and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV
>   iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be
>   removed in 0.20.

Pay attention to that, and use the `model_selection` module like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
```

Then you will not get error with my code.

Comment: Ok, I'll try using this.

Comment: This will not work as TimeSeriesSplit is not iterable

Comment: @DhruvBhardwaj. I have checked this code before posting and its working as intented. Please share more details of your current error. Also please read the updated answer

Comment: tss = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=10).split(X_1)
kn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, algorithm='brute')
sc = cross_val_score(kn, X1, y1, cv=tss, scoring='accuracy')

Comment: I have the latest version of scikit-learn installed as you mentioned

Comment: @DhruvBhardwaj You are doing it wrong and different from the code you gave in question. I have updated the answer to correct your code.

Comment: Oh, I was just trying to make my code look cleaner. So, how to resolve this too many indices error as far as I know the split() function will return the indices of the train and test data after Time-based Splitting

Comment: @DhruvBhardwaj Dont use the `split()` function. Just send the `TimeseriesSplit()`  without calling `split` to `cross_val_score`, as I am doing. `cross_val_score` will do that automatically

Comment: TypeError: 'TimeSeriesSplit' object is not iterable @Vivek Kumar

Comment: How can you iterate the time series object just like that As far as I Know something is wrong

Comment: @DhruvBhardwaj As I said, cross_val_score will iterate by calling the `split()` method inside automatically, no need for you to do it. Just try my code and if still not clear, please edit the question with the exact code and data.

Comment: @DhruvBhardwaj Is it not working? What error are you getting?

Comment: @DhruvBhardwaj Post the full stack trace of error.I am not getting any error on your code with my data

Comment: @VivekKumar Would you consider this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75818230/what-is-the-best-practice-to-apply-cross-validation-using-timeseriessplit-over)? Thanks in advance.